# How to restrict user from uploading file other than pdf using react dropzone component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I have a web app where I am using react drop zone. I want to use the same app on a mobile screen. I want to restrict the user to upload only pdf files I am using the following configuration:-

```
this.djsConfig = 
{ addRemoveLinks: true,
 acceptedFiles: ".pdf",
 autoProcessQueue: false,
 maxFiles: 1,
 dictDefaultMessage: "Click or Drop files here to upload"
 };
```

On the mobile screen, I am able to upload and remove a .pdf file but I am also able to upload other file formats like .png and.jpeg how do I restrict a user from uploading other file formats on mobile screens. Also if a wrong file format is uploaded I am unable to remove the file on mobile screens whereas on a desktop screen it does not allow you to select another file format.
This is a browser-specific issue since it works in other browsers but not in chrome.

Comment: Do your validation server-side, not just on the client-side.

Comment: [react-dropzone documentation about accepting specific file types](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Accepting%20specific%20file%20types)

Comment: @ChrisPickford thank you for your prompt response. This application was developed as a client-side application and is deployed on AWS S3 bucket so I would try to solve the problem client-side if possible.

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda I tested this in different browsers it works on other browsers it doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I tested this in different browsers it works on other browsers it doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: From the documentation I linked "For example, the following example won't work even in Chrome [...] but this one will: [..]". Maybe that's the issue, but I'm not that familiar with `dropzone`, so I really can't help you further

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda Thank you so much for your help I tried the document you sent but it still does not work on chrome for me. I want to completely restrict the user from attaching anything other than a .pdf file.

Answer (score -3):

just give accept: 'application/pdf', it will work,